# Get location lattitude and longitude value from place name

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am writing a JavaScript function to return latitude and longitude values given the place name.I used google map API to get the result.However I am not getting the result I want to be.Here is my code to get the result.

```
function getLocationCoordinates(place)
{    
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = place;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        //alert(results[0].geometry.location.H+","+results[0].geometry.location.L);
       return results[0].geometry.location.H+","+results[0].geometry.location.L;      

    } else {
        return "0,0";
    }
    });
}
```

I am getting the value "undefined" when I call the function  getLocationCoordinates('kollam').It is supposed to return the value '8.8800,76.6000'.However when I alert out 'results[0].geometry.location.H+","+results[0].geometry.location.L',it is showing the right value.How do I make this function to return the correct value.

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous, you can't return anything from its callback function, you need to use the results in the callback function where/when they are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code

First `geocoder.geocode()` is asynchronous which means you won't be able to return the response to your outer function as the data won't have returned from google servers before the function completes.

Second...even if it wasn't asychncronous the `return` from inside the geocode callback does not return to the outer function.

Currently `getLocationCoordinates()` will always return undefined since there is nothing being returned

You need to either return a promise that gets resolved with the gecode response or consume the data inside the geocode callback.